# Clone a Smart Contract

Tags: security, clone

I'm an artist trying to publish his own contract. I don't have solidarity knowledge, but I can read/understand codes in general. So I found this collection minted yesterday: https://etherscan.io/address/0x334ec5498b9fe6575d118d89a8c9f3b4472f7862#code Their pricing model is what I'm exactly looking for. They set the first nft free per wallet, then it's 0.003 eth.

So I clone the contract from etherscan, deployed it with following this tutorial: https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-deploy-nft-smart-contracts-9271ce5e91c0 This is my clone contract: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x7a72d7c674107ca51941f2fe8cff7985148f5ee3 It worked perfect. I tested it with minting, admin functions, and interacting with another wallet, etc.

Obviously I'll change ipfs, metadata, artwork, price, etc. But I wonder if this method is safe? Can original contract owner access to my contract? I would appreciate your help. I can't afford web3 developer. I need to do this my own.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would not advice just copying a contract, **but in your case** the `onlyOwner` modifier is what will keep you as the owner of the newly deployed contract and the person who should withdraw the funds from the contract.

By default, the owner of an `Ownable` contract, which MyNFT is, is the account that deployed it. If you want to default to a different thing you must modify the constructor.

**So, No** the original creator of that contract will not have access to yours.